# Existence of a sequence that converges to infimum of a function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

X is a compact subset of $\Re^{n}$. A upper and lower bounded function f is defined that f:X $\rightarrow$ $\Re$. Does a sequence of {$x_n$} always exist so that f($x_n$)$\rightarrow$ $\inf$[f(x)].

I understand that in a bounded subset X of $\Re$, a decreasing sequence {$x_n$} will converge to inf(X). But what I am confused about in my case is whether the behavior of this function f will affect the same results to be applied?

Is this possible to be proved by contradiction? Say, if there no sequence sequence of {$x_n$} so that sequence {f$(x_n)$} converges to inf(f(x)). Then it contradicts the definition of inf(f(x)). Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If, in general (X,d) is a compact metric space, and f is a continuous function from X to R then the infinimum is attained. Else, consider the interval [0,1] with the usual absolute value metric (it's compact) and consider the function f defined on [0,1] that takes the value $-x$ if $ 0\leq x<1$ and takes the value 0 at 1. the infinimum of f is -1 but is never attained!

Comment: thanks mich95, but in your example, I can still find a sequence $x_n \rightarrow 1$ so that $f(x_n)\rightarrow -1$. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Ouch, I misread you, sorry! I think that you can always do that, but not so sure. Let m = inf f(x). Then for all $\epsilon>0$ you can find $x$ such that $m \leq f(x) <m+ \epsilon$, Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ and define $x_{n}$ such that $m \leq f(x_{n}) < m+\frac{1}{n}$. $f(x_{n})$ converges to m by squeeze, Do you think this works?

Comment: Thanks, I guess you're right. I am not quite sure either.

Comment: @baimiaomark The approach above is correct. It is a special case of the fact that for every bounded set, there is a sequence converging to the infimum/supremum.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Thanks for your reply. But I am still confused. I understand that there is a sequence converging to infimum in $\Re$. But how to make sure there is a sequence of {$x_n$} so that sequence {f$(x_n)$} converges as well given the fact I do not necessarily know the behavior of such function f()? Is this possible to be proved by contradiction? Say, if there no sequence sequence of {$x_n$} so that sequence {f$(x_n)$} converges to inf(f(x)). Then it contradicts the definition of inf(f(x)). Am I right?

Comment: @mich95 I am a little confused when you say you can find x such that $m\leq f(x) <m+\epsilon$. I edited the post to explain my question. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Consider the set $S=\lbrace f(x) : x \in X \rbrace$. For all $\epsilon >0$ m+$\epsilon$ is not  a lower bound of S, hence we can find an element t of S such that $m \leq t <m+ \epsilon$, and an element t of S is just of the form f($x_{0}$)  where $x_{0}$ is in X.